# Float data showing property of string? Float cant be added in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I got a vix data from somewhere and tried to do some research. While checking the data, i found the data can't be analyzed becasue for some reason it is reporting error of

> Exception has occurred: TypeError
> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

I am using this code to check everything:

```
import pandas as pd

data_path = r"\Stock Data\VIX.csv"
raw_data = pd.read_csv(data_path)

sum = 0
for index, row in raw_data['Price'].iteritems():
    print(row)
    print(type(float(row)))
    sum = sum + row
    print(sum)
    print(index)
```

The code reported the above error here: (see attached image)

Do you guys know why this could happen? All the data seems to be float but it is not running because it is saying it is string? Thanks very much.

[the original data subset where the code stopped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9REY.png) \n
[the place code stopped according to the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxJQT.png)

Comment: `row` is still the original string unless you reassign the result of `float(row)` to the name: `row = float(row)`. You are only testing if a string *can* be parsed as a `float`, not if the data itself *is* a `float`.

Comment: or perhaps look at the `dtype` parameter of `pandas.read_csv()`

Comment: You can use `dtype` parameter of `read_csv` or cast to float later: `result = raw_data['Price'].astype('float64').sum()`, Also without implicit iteration it will be much faster. Please don't use builtin names for variables, `sum` is widely used function!

Comment: @SUTerliakov thanks! I tried sum and it was not working... so that is why i am doing iteritems() in order to see where the problem is. This is the error when I did raw_data['Price'].astype('float64').sum()..
Exception has occurred: ValueError
could not convert string to float: 'Price'

Do you know why?

Comment: Somewhere in your column there's value that can't be converted to float. Maybe commas instead of dots, for example, or something else strange. Try to iterate like you did and find value that cannot be converted to float: `for index, row in raw_data['Price'].iteritems(): try: float(row); except ValueError: print(row)`

Comment: @SUTerliakov Bro this is working and i find the error. Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are casting row to float, so `print(type(float(row)))` will certainly print `float`. Have you tried doing `sum += float(row)`?

Furthermore, to get the sum of a column, rather do `raw_data['Price'].sum()` which is more efficient and less verbose. You might have to convert the type before doing this like

```
raw_data['Price'].astype(float).sum()
```

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks. I tried to use .sum() but it didn't work. Here is the error reported on doing that: Exception has occurred: ValueError
could not convert string to float: 'Price'.. do you know why?

Comment: This means that some entries in the Price columns cannot be converted from string to float. Most likely there are missing values represented by some string that cannot be converted to float. What you can do is specify these values in read_csv use na_values. This will transform them into NaN which means you can do raw_data['Price'].dropna().sum() afterwards.

Comment: Hi Simon, I tried again still no luck.. and same error. I was able to locate the data with issue with my original iterrow() method and the errror was reported here (see this pic): https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxJQT.png

Comment: Then I got back and see the original CSV file and it shows me the error is with this line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9REY.png
It does not seem to be a NA value. Do you know why is that?

Comment: I wish I could attach my CSV file here but I could not... :(